# Any struct to byte[] and back

Tags: c#

Say, there's code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MYSTRUCT1 s = new MYSTRUCT1();
        s.a = 1; s.b = 2; s.c = 3;
        byte[] buffer = StructToByteArray(s);
        MYSTRUCT1 ss = new MYSTRUCT1();
        ByteArrayToAnyStruct(ss, buffer); 
    }

    struct MYSTRUCT1 { public int a; public int b; public int c; }
    struct MYSTRUCT2 { public int a; public string b; }

    static byte[] StructToByteArray(object s)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(s)];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(s));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, data.Length);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return data;
    }
    static void ByteArrayToAnyStruct(object s, byte[] buffer)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, buffer.Length);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, s); <---- what's wrong with this structure?
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Converting to buffer works Ok, but back way rises Exception
What's wrong with this structure in ByteArrayToAnyStruct?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: it says the "s" should be reference type not value (because it's struct)

Comment: should I use extra class to duplicate the struct? :)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque exception is/was The structure must not be a value class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! Fredou!

You're right with **s = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, s.GetType());**
I've changed to:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MYSTRUCT1 s = new MYSTRUCT1();
        s.a = 1; s.b = 2; s.c = 3;
        byte[] buffer = StructToByteArray(s);
        MYSTRUCT1 ss = (MYSTRUCT1)ByteArrayToAnyStruct(typeof(MYSTRUCT1), buffer); 
    }

    struct MYSTRUCT1 { public int a; public int b; public int c; }
    struct MYSTRUCT2 { public int a; public string b; }

    static byte[] StructToByteArray(object s)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(s)];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(s));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, data.Length);
        return data;
    }
    public static object ByteArrayToAnyStruct(Type type, byte[] buffer)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, buffer.Length);
        object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, type);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Will mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

to do what you want you need to use the overloaded method call that return an object like this

replace

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, s); //<---- what's wrong with this structure?
```

with

```
s = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, s.GetType());
```

you also need to change the calling line with

```
ByteArrayToAnyStruct(ref ss, buffer);
```

and the method signature with

```
static void ByteArrayToAnyStruct<T>(ref T s, byte[] buffer)  where T : struct
```

[working fiddler example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqkfPv)

Comment: Well, but it doesn't copy data from buffer to s :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, but it doesn't like ref to object. That's the problem also

Comment: @RobertKirk don't use object, use generic like i do